# Is the alert system still in the main client's code? Will it be removed?

Tags: client, alert-system

It is said that Satoshi removed the alert system from the client ... still, there are at least some leftovers in.

Is the alert system functioning in 0.3.24? Are there plans to remove all traces of it?

See also [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/583/what-is-the-alert-system-in-the-bitcoin-protocol-how-does-it-work/590#590).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Satoshi didn't remove the alert system; it still exists in the client. However, it cannot trigger RPC safe mode as it could before.

There are no plans to remove all traces of it, as all it does in its current state is display a warning message.

Comment: Citation please.

Comment: main.cpp:  else if (strCommand == "alert") when processing network messages.  And see the ProcessAlert() method in that file.

Comment: So to disable the alert system we'd literally just have to remove/comment out one elseif block? Just glancing at the code I don't see where it would break anything (well other than the thing we're intentionally trying to break). I'll gladly fork, modify and submit a pull request **myself** if it'll start the conversation among the *real* devs... I legitimately think this feature needs to go away ASAP.